# Vuejs computed property with multiple checkbox filters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I am trying to make a solution for filtering results using checkboxes as simple as possible and as readable as possible.

I have a computed property called filteredPositions that looks like this. But it won't work with multiple filters on one array. Does anyone have a good solution for this problem?

Here is the computed property.

```
filteredPositions() {
    if (this.checkedFilters.includes("SE")) {
        return this.positions.filter(position => position.country_id == 1);
    }
    if (this.checkedFilters.includes("US")) {
        return this.positions.filter(position => position.country_id == 2);
    }
}
```

Testdata

```
data() {
    return {
        positions: [],
        filters: [
            {
                name: 'SE',
            },
            {
                name: 'US',
            }
        ],
        checkedFilters: ['SE', 'US'],
    }
},
```

Here is a JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/9657/

Answer (score 0):

Your `filteredPositions` filters only one position because of the return in if (it won't reach the other one). You need to check if your selected filters contain current position's name.

https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/9712/

```
filteredPositions () {
  return this.positions.filter(position => this.checkedFilters.includes(position.name));
}
```

Comment: My fiddle was not really close to reality. I made a quick change here on how the data is represented. https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/9740/

Comment: If you want to filter by `country_id`, then just change `:value` to `filter.country_id` and make `filteredPositions` filter by `country_id` again:
https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/9743/